# How to denote a Request Facade by a variable in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-6

I am doing some experiment to make my controllers as much dynamic as I can. Let me give you a brief overview. I have a controller Logo Controller which I have set up like this:

```
use App\Models\Logo;

class LogoController extends Controller
{
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $data['entity']         = 'logo';
        
        $newEntityObj                = new Logo;
        $newEntityObj->title         = $title;                         // set title 
        $newEntityObj->type          = $type;                          // set type
        $saveNewEntityData           = $newEntityObj->save();          // save the entity data 
        ------------------
        -------------------
    }
}
```

Now I made some changes like:

using a variable to denote the Logo Model.

```
$modelClass             = "App\\Models\\" . ucfirst($data['entity']);
```

And then, using the $modelClass variable to execution Eloquent actions on it, like this:-

```
$newEntityObj                = new $modelClass;
$newEntityObj->title         = $title;                         // set title 
$newEntityObj->type          = $type;                          // set type
$saveNewEntityData           = $newEntityObj->save();          // save the entity data
```

So the Logo Controller Class has been updated to:

```
use App\Models\Logo;

class LogoController extends Controller
{
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $data['entity']         = 'logo';
        $modelClass             = "App\\Models\\" . ucfirst($data['entity']);

        $newEntityObj                = new $modelClass;
        $newEntityObj->title         = $title;                         // set title 
        $newEntityObj->type          = $type;                          // set type
        $saveNewEntityData           = $newEntityObj->save();          // save the entity data 
        ------------------
        -------------------
    }
}
```

Now I have created a Validationb Request File to use it for form validation. I am using it like this:

```
// Request Validation Inclusion //
use App\Http\Requests\AdminRequests\LogoValidation\LogoRequest;

public function add(LogoRequest $request)
{
    --------------------------
    --------------------------
}
```

Now instead of writing `public function add(LogoRequest $request)` I want to make it more dynamic. Something like this:

```
class LogoController extends Controller
{
    public static $classEntity          = 'logo';
    public static $classFormattedEntity = null;
    public static $classRequestVariable = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $entityArray    = explode('-', str_replace('_', '-', self::$classEntity));
        foreach($entityArray as $keyEntity => $rowEntity)
        {
            if($keyEntity !== 0)
                $entityArray[$keyEntity] = ucfirst($rowEntity);
        }
        self::$classFormattedEntity = implode('', $entityArray);
        self::$classRequestVariable = "App\\Http\\Requests\\AdminRequests\\" . ucfirst(self::$classFormattedEntity) . "Validation\\" . ucfirst(self::$classFormattedEntity) . "Request";
    }

    public function add(self::$classRequestVariable $request)
    {
        ..............................
        ..............................
    }
}
```

The variable `self::$classRequestVariable` actually prints `App\Http\Requests\AdminRequests\LogoValidation\LogoRequest`

But when I am writing `public function add(self::$classRequestVariable $request)` instead of `public function add(LogoRequest $request)` I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: You don't put `self::$classRequestVariable` inside the function declaration, you simply use it within the function. `public function add($request){ self::$classRequestVariable }`

Comment: @TimLewis Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: Now that you've fixed that, does your code work? Do you have a new error? The only issue you've pointed out in your code is that, which that comment should fix, so if you want more help, you'll need to provide new/more information on what isn't working now.

Comment: I did this:- `public function add($request){ self::$classRequestVariable; ........}` . However, I still get error. It says `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\admin\LogoController::add()`

Comment: Don't do that literally... You need to change your function declaration and remove `self::$classRequestVariable`, so just `public function add($request) { }`, then *somewhere* in that code, use the variable. And that error would come if you're calling `add()` without passing a `$request` variable to do. Please update your code to show your new code and error (you have 11k rep on Stackoverflow; you should know this process by now)

Comment: The error is coming event if I write `public function add($request)`. The Facade `Request` is must to make a call, since it is a controller method used in routing and which accepts request calls. Even if I keep $request, it is telling me that no parameter is sent. That's because the URL needs param too while running on browser.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to do, parameter injection like `LogoRequest $request`, or `SomeOtherRequest $request`. If you just omit that and define it as `$request`, it _should_ work. But yeah, I don't think you can dynamically define it like that TBH.

Comment: Yes, now you are getting my point. Actually, I am using the Model Name, and Request Validation files based on the entity name. So if entity is `bus`, model name would be `Bus`, Request file would be `BusRequest`. I was trying any process to just set a variable and the Request files, Model files would be loaded, imported or used based on the variable value.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're trying to do. In this case, I think you're trying to make something dynamic that really doesn't need to be; you're in `LogoController`, just type `LogoRequest $request`. Beyond that, I don't know of a way to make `LogoRequest` based off a variable, since TypeHinting in function declarations doesn't work like that.